# Can JQuery do all this functionality?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

As I am newbie to JQuery. I have certain questions in mind regarding JQuery.
Can  I make complete website with Jquery? 
Means in ASP.Net website we use **Server Controls** to design page, Can we make all this functionality on **.ASPX page using JQuery**?
If yes, then how to **handle server side events**?
For designing .ASPX pages, what we prefer to use? **JQuery standard controls or Plugin**?

Comment: I suggest you to google it first, when you get stuck at a specific point just paste the code which bothered you and guys here will give solutions for that.

Comment: Yes, I am agree with you. But as I need to start development, I should know that what is beneficial from performance point of view, & is it possible to use JQuery completely to replace ASP.Net server controls.

Comment: jQuery is quite robust and powerful, Use `AJAX` with your application with all your serverside events and do dom manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. JQuery is not  a server-side framework. It's a client side DOM Manipulation domain specific language and API that enables client-side code to work cross-browser, and includes a variety of utility and helper functions for AJAX, deferred callback resolution, and generic functional programming.

In short, it is not meant to replace your server-side code.

Comment: (Just to nitpick my own answer, it *can* be used on the server, in the case of a javascript server environment like Node.js with the node-jquery module... technically).

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery framework is only a javascript library which means it can only handle events or actions on the client-side. It doesn't matter what backend you are using for your website (PHP, ASP.Net, Python), javascript only works once the page has been rendered and sent to the browser. Try reading up on the docs for jQuery here: http://docs.jquery.com/

If you have any questions specifically about jQuery programming, we would be more than happy to answer them.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph Torraca , I will surely go through it.